# Workaround for Selenium IDE 2.0.0 on Firefox 22

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

On Firefox 21, S-IDE worked fine.  Just upgraded to the officially released FF22, and any test I try to run errors out:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js, lineNumber -> 309, columnNumber -> 8
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Long live continuous releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There's a fix now available](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841), but you may encounter a similar problem with keyPress commands.

Comment: Indeed, I downloaded the "unreleased" version 2.1.0 which remedies some, but not all of the problems. In my case its the `typeKeys` command which is still broken.

Comment: Replacing `typeKeys` with `sendKeys` as described in http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2012/07/19/new-selenese-command-sendkeys/ made my tests run through successfully again.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, the scripts stop on any 'Click' action when running FF22. Reverting back to FF21 is the best solution for now.

Comment: Not if my users want to run FF22, or auto-update by accident.

Comment: But your comment about clicks seems accurate, +1.

Comment: FF21 is available at ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/21.0/

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to version 2.1.0 and all of old selenium jobs started to work fine. The official release for version 2.1.0 is on July fifth but it seems they have made it available probably because so many people are now having problems.

here is the link which has the version 2.1.0 available 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: It depends whether your test cases use any key commands besides sendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the following issues with FF22 and Selenium IDE 2.0..  which you may also encounter.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963084